# Url shows in print, why?

Tags: html, css

When printing a page, the url of a link shows, can someone tell me why?

It's a link, it should only output the linktext as it normally does?'

Comment: Surely (most of the time) that's the behaviour you want? Link text alone isn't a lot of use on a printed page.

Comment: Are you using the HTML5 Boilerplate?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has been closed. Not only does it make sense to me, two posters have posted a possible cause and a possible fix.

Answer (score 4):

If you ARE using HTML5 Boilerplate, look for the line:

```
a[href]:after { content: " (" attr(href) ")"; }
```

that causes the URLs to print

Answer (score 1):

That's a printer setting. You can turn it off in your print properties when printing.

Comment: So no way to turn it off by using css?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but maybe this media query would work:

```
@media print {
    a:after {
        content: "";
        }
    }
```